# Don't show autocomplete in eclipse when backspace all letters

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin

When i type `j`, it props up a list of suggestions,  and when i backspace `j` and there is no letters, but it will still props up some suggestions about recent used variables and methods.
So I am using Eclipse vrapper and mapped `jj` for `<Esc>`, and when i'm type `jj`, it will props up suggestions like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbvZ2.png).
I can press `<Esc>` to close it or remove `j` from the **Auto activation triggers for Java** to stop autocomplete for `j`. Is there any settings that can stop showing suggestions when backspce all letters?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck "Enable auto activation" in "Preference / Content Assist".